# Why C readlink() has ELOOP as a possible error

Tags: c, symlink, readlink

**Background**

I read about the Open Group Specification about [readlink()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/readlink.html), and there is an error called `ELOOP`, which indicates "A loop exists in symbolic links encountered during resolution of the path argument.", so I assume this function will continue path resolution until encountering a non-link file.

However, I did an experiment and found that `readlink()` only resolve the passed in `path` argument and just stops there but not keep resolving until reaching a non-link file.

**My Problem**

1. If it's for `realpath()`, that makes all the sense to have `ELOOP` as a possible error. But why does `ELOOP` even exist for `readlink()` while it only resolves the path once?
2. I saw this on the spec "The [ELOOP] optional error condition is added to align with the IEEE P1003.1a draft standard", does that mean the behavior of `readlink()` (whether it keeps resolving until reaching a non-link file) depends on implementation?

my gcc version is `8.2.1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`readlink` gives you the immediate target of a symbolic link. But what if resolving the path to the symbolic link involves another symlink?

Take `readlink("/foo/bar")` as an example. It's supposed to return the link target of `bar`, but if `/foo` is a symlink pointing to itself, you'll get `ELOOP` because `readlink` has to resolve the directory part before getting to the final entry.

See also [`man path_resolution`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html).